# C++ Capitalization function failing for multiple inputs

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm running into an issue where I have moved a snippet of capitalization code into its own function because I would like to easily call it more than once. It works fine if left in the main body, but once I'm calling it as its own function it will not capitalize the first word of the second input. This happens for all subsequent inputs if I call the function multiple times. I think there is an issue with my last variable but I'm not sure.

```
    using namespace std;
    string capitalize(string capitalizeThis)
    {
        getline(cin, capitalizeThis);
        for_each(capitalizeThis.begin(), capitalizeThis.end(), [](char & c) {
        static int last = ' ';
        if (last == ' ' && c != ' ' && isalpha(c))
            c = ::toupper(c); //capitalize if conditions fulfilled 
        last = c; //iterate
    });
    return capitalizeThis;
}
int main()
{
    string eventName, customerName;
    cout << "\nPlease enter your name:" << endl;
    customerName = capitalize(customerName);
    cout << customerName << endl;

    cout << "\nPlease enter the name of your event:" << endl;
    eventName = capitalize(eventName);
    cout << eventName << endl;

    cout << endl << endl;
    system("pause");
    return (0);
}
```

My output looks like this:

```
Please enter your name:
my name
My Name

Please enter the name of your event:
this event
this Event


Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: don't use a static variable, it's remembering `e` from `my name` and not being reset to `' '` when you start on `this event`

Answer (score 1):

Value of last persists through the function calls as it is a static variable. That means that each call uses the value of last character from the previous call. You can change it to capture a new variable every time :

```
string capitalize(string capitalizeThis)
{
    getline(cin, capitalizeThis);
    char last = ' ';
    for_each(capitalizeThis.begin(), capitalizeThis.end(), [&last](char & c) 
    {
        if (last == ' ' && c != ' ' && isalpha(c))
            c = ::toupper(c); //capitalize if conditions fulfilled 
        last = c; //iterate
    });
    return capitalizeThis;
}
```

---

On a side note you're passing `string capitalizeThis` by value. You can't change the value of the passed string in the function, so by passing a string from `main` you're not doing anything.
You should read the input in main and pass it to the function by reference (as the function should do one thing at a time anyway):

```
void capitalize(string &capitalizeThis)
{       
    char last = ' ';
    for_each(capitalizeThis.begin(), capitalizeThis.end(), [&last](char & c) 
    {
        if (last == ' ' && c != ' ' && isalpha(c))
            c = ::toupper(c); //capitalize if conditions fulfilled 
        last = c; //iterate
    });        
}
```

And call it from `main`

```
int main()
{
    string eventName, customerName;
    cout << "\nPlease enter your name:" << endl;
    getline(cin, customerName);
    capitalize(customerName);
    cout << customerName << endl;
    ...        
}
```

Comment: Also, a simple for ranged-loop might be a better choice than for_each.

Comment: Oh, okay, that was a big misunderstanding of how static worked on my part. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your function works the first time since `last` is initialized to `' '`. One way to make it work for subsequent calls:

1. Move it out of the lambda function.
2. Reset its value.

---

```
string capitalize(string capitalizeThis)
{
   static int last = ' ';
   getline(cin, capitalizeThis);
   for_each(capitalizeThis.begin(), capitalizeThis.end(), [](char & c) {
            if (last == ' ' && c != ' ' && isalpha(c))
            {
               c = ::toupper(c); //capitalize if conditions fulfilled 
            }
            last = c; //iterate
            });

   last = ' ';
   return capitalizeThis;
}
```